# AS3 Error 1061 Reference with Static Type

Tags: actionscript-3, function, flash

I'm new to AS3, and trying to create a draggable element. However, I keep getting error 1061, and I don't know why, because I'm pretty sure I don't have any spelling errors or the like. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
package {

import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

public class Script extends MovieClip{
    public var value:Number;

    private var max:Number;
    private var min:Number;

    public function Draggable(){
        min = erhu_mc.y;
        max = erhu_mc.height - Erhu_H3_btn.height;
        Erhu_H3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragHandle);
    }

    function dragHandle(event:MouseEvent):void {
        Erhu_H3_btn.startDrag(new Rectangle, false,(0,min,0,max));
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
    }

    function stopDragging(event:MouseEvent):void {
        Erhu_H3_btn.stopDrag();
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because `Erhu_H3_btn` is the name of a class, not an instance name of an object on the stage.

Comment: I don't understand...'Erhu_H3_btn' is the name of my button, which is on my stage...so why is it a class and not an instance name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your current class.

1. `Erhu_H3_btn.startDrag(new Rectangle, false,(0,min,0,max));` needs to be: `Erhu_H3_btn.startDrag(false,new Rectangle(0,min,0,max));`
2. You can't directly reference objects from the timeline from a class.[[ref]](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/775681?start=0&tstart=0) You will need to either pass a reference to the object, or a reference to the stage. For example, the following returns null:
    `import flash.display.*;
   public class Script extends MovieClip {
   public function Script() {
       trace(stage);
   }`

I copied and moded your code so that it works on a frame.:

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;


var value:Number;
var max:Number;
var min:Number;
Draggable();


function Draggable(){
min = Erhu_H3_btn.y;
max = Erhu_H3_btn.y += 100;
Erhu_H3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragHandle);
}

function dragHandle(event:MouseEvent):void {
Erhu_H3_btn.startDrag(false,new Rectangle(0,min,0,max));
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
}

function stopDragging(event:MouseEvent):void {
Erhu_H3_btn.stopDrag();
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I get the 'error 1061', 'call to a possibly undefined method through a reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton' for both 'startDrag' and 'stopDrag'

Comment: put this: ((simpleButtonMovieClipName) as SimpleButton).startDrag...
or
put this: ((simpleButtonMovieClipName) as MovieClip).startDrag...

Comment: I tried both directly under the code you gave me...neither got rid of `error 1061`. I also get `error 1120`, access of undefined property, for both, and error 1119, access of possibly undefined property through reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton, for `((simpleButtonMovieClipName) as SimpleButton).startDrag`

Comment: Error 1061: trying to use a function which is not inherited by that data type. need to convert to movie clip. Error 1120: Null reference exception. Can't find obtain reference to object on the stage.
It also sounds like you're still trying to do this from a class without passing a reference to the stage..

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I still don't quite know how to solve them, though...do you mean that I can't use the `startDrag` function on buttons? Also, what do you mean by 'passing a reference to the stage'? Sorry for bothering you, and thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use start drag on a button, but you need to convert it to a movie clip in order to do so. i.e. put this: `((Erhu_H3_btn) as MovieClip).startDrag(false,new Rectangle(0,min,0,max));`
When I say pass a reference to your class. Create a `public var` in your class called `stageReference`. Then from the frame where you are using this class, set this class var to `this.stage`. Then from your class you will be able to do: `(stageReference.getChildByName("Erhu_H3_btn") as MovieClip).startDrag(false,new Rectangle(0,min,0,max));`
If this doesn't help, I will make a project and send it to you. :)

Comment: Yes! That would be great! Could you please send the project to me? Thanks, and sorry again for all the trouble I'm causing you! :D

Comment: All good, I will whip it up when im home from work for you :)

Comment: You didn't have a visible email associated with your account, so i've just got a dropbox for you. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88797529/13_10_14_SimpleButtonDragExample.zip Hope this helps,  ^___^